# How do I find all network clients (WinXp) that have local printers connected?

Tags: networking, windows-xp, printing

I have about 300 workstations and I want to know which of those computers have local printers connected to them. Not necessary shared local printers, and get a list of the computers and possibly the model of the printer. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you wrote that the clients are win xp, I'm assuning that you have an active directory. So, you could build a script using WMI to do it to you.

Take a look at [this script](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/45ce3543-b951-44da-9315-49d0e741ba1d), it will retrieve information about printers installed on a local machine.

And you could join it with [this script](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/80a75a64-980f-414d-b084-01c83f6ce261), that will retrieve all the computers registerd in your domain.

By joining both scripts you will end up with a script that will walk over your network retriving printing information.

At [this site](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/) you will find lots of good resources.

Answer (score 0):

A variety of network inventory tools will help you with this - [Spiceworks](http://www.spiceworks.com) is available free (although might have a client count limit on the free version).  There are others, and you might already have something, especially if you have a deployment tool for setting up those workstations.  Many deployment tools include inventory functions.